# how to pass id of link to angularJS controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have something like this:

```
<a href="#" title="Post 1" id="car1"> Audi car 
</a>

<a href="#" title="Post 1" id="car2"> BMW car 
</a>
```

how can I pass the id to the controller ? I tried the following:

```
<a href="#" title="Post 1" id="car1" onclick="getCarID(this.id)" > Audi car  </a>
```

This works outside the Angular controller but I want it to be inside the controller so I figured out that I need to use `ng-click` but then `this.id` will not work. How to make it work ?
where my controller and getCarID I have it like this:

```
angular.module('myModule')
.controller('carController', function($scope)
{

$scope.getCarID = function(elementID)
    {  
        var car = document.getElementById(elementID);
        console.log(elementID + " is being pressed");
    }
)}
```

If something is not clear or need extra explaining then please comment it out and I will edit the question.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Please show the relevant pieces of your controller code.  Especially `getCarID`.

Comment: @zero298 I added it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the event's target's id ?

```
<a href="#" title="Post 1" id="car1" ng-click="getCarID($event)">
```

And in your controller :

```
$scope.getCarID = function(event) {
   var id = event.target.id;
}
```

```js
function Ctrl($scope) {

    $scope.action = function(event) {
        console.log('clicked id is: ' + event.target.id);
    };
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
         <a id="123" ng-click="action($event)">click</a>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It says `event is not defined`. How can I define it ?

Comment: and it need to be a scope function so that I can access it from the view. Right ?!

Comment: you need to use the $event from the ng-click, and reference it in your function `ng-click="func($event)"` and `func function($event)...`

Comment: I saw this solution on another question on stackoverflow but this only works with button and it doesn't work with <a> link. Thanks for your time but this is still not working :(

Comment: @samjackson it totally works with <a> tags. Test the snippet.

Comment: @RogerC that is so weird. I tried it out on my code but I'm only getting `clicked id is: ` without the id. Thanks so much though. At least now I know the problem is not with this.

Comment: Codepen of Roger's example with newer angular.js version: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LrZVRL

Comment: @RogerC found the problem :D thanks again for your solution. The problem was that I has image inside the link and I had to add ng-click for the image inside the link as well for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the missing quotation mark, `<a href="#" title="Post 1" id="car1" onclick="getCarID(this.id)" > Audi car  </a>`

Comment: This is not the problem. It's just typing mistake which I fixed. Thanks for letting me know though

Comment: Gotcha, use a scope function then with ng-click, similar to above. $scope.getCarID = function() { var id = event.target.id; console.log(id+ " is being pressed"); }

Comment: I tried it out but it still says `event is not defined`  :(